# Utilising $scope.apply()

Tags: angularjs, model, scope, apply

I have the following which works fine, drawing info from a RESTful api feed

```
app.controller('servicesController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$interval',
    function($scope, $location, $http, $interval) {

        var getData = function() {

        // Initialize $scope using the value of the model attribute, e.g.,
        $scope.url = "https://(remote link to JSON api)";

        $http.get($scope.url).success(function(data) {
            $scope.listOfServices = data.runningServices; // get data from json
        });

        };

        getData();
        $interval(getData(), 10000);
    }
]);
```

However my view is not updating every 10 seconds as expected. I have read that I need to use $scope.apply() somewhere in this above code.

I tried placing the following (in the appropriate place above)

```
 $http.get($scope.url).success(function(data) {
            $scope.listOfServices = data.runningServices; // get data from json
            $scope.apply(); //I also tried $scope.runningServices.apply()
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.apply` is not your problem, the scope will be digested automatically at the end of the `$http` request *and* `$interval`. Certain actions automatically "inform" Angular that the scope may have changed and trigger a digest; only if you're writing "non-Angular" code may you have to explicitly trigger a scope digest, since otherwise Angular wouldn't notice any changes.

No, your issue is that you're calling `getData()`, and then have **its return value** (`undefined`) execute every ten seconds. Which is obviously nonsense. You just want to pass *the function itself* to `$interval`:

```
$interval(getData, 10000);
// look ma, ^^^^^, no parentheses
```

Comment: I will consider mysefl slapped on the back of the head, appreciate the detailed overview, works prefectly!